# unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl RSA::encrypt_or_decrypt(float,float,float)" (?encrypt_or_decrypt@RSA@@SAMMMM@Z)

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, libraries

I can't get an app to use a c++ library I made.

The library is in https://github.com/Coder4360/RSA/.

The program is called RSA Test and I can't build it (I'm using Visual Studio 2019):

- Error (active) E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name  RSA Test    C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\RSA Test\RSA Test\RSA Test.cpp, line 11
- Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl RSA::encrypt_or_decrypt(float,float,float)" (?encrypt_or_decrypt@RSA@@SAMMMM@Z)    RSA Test    C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\RSA Test\RSA Test\RSA Test.obj, line 1
- Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_encrypt_or_decrypt RSA Test    C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\RSA Test\RSA Test\RSA Test.obj, line 1
- Error LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  RSA Test    C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\RSA Test\x64\Release\RSA Test.exe, line 1

The problems might be here:

RSAlib.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef RSALIB_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RSALIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" RSALIB_API float generate_encryption_number(float prime_1, float prime_2);
extern "C" RSALIB_API float generate_decryption_number(float prime_1, float prime_2, float public_exponent);
extern "C" RSALIB_API float encrypt_or_decrypt(float data, float exponent, float encryption_number);

class RSA
{
public:
    static float generate_encryption_number(float prime_1, float prime_2);
    static float generate_decryption_number(float prime_1, float prime_2, float public_exponent);
    static float encrypt_or_decrypt(float data, float exponent, float encryption_number);
};
```

RSA Test.cpp

```
// RSA Test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "RSAlib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float encrypted = RSA::encrypt_or_decrypt(20, 3, 3127);
    float decrypted = encrypt_or_decrypt(encrypted, 2011, 3127);
    cout << "Encrypted: " << encrypted << endl;
    cout << "Decrypted: " << decrypted << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to export the functions from the DLL library you made.   Google for `declspec(dllexport)` Also, your header file has both a "flat C" API as well as C++ functions declared. Your library only has the C++ functions defined.

Comment: I solved it by removing the copy-pasted mess at the start and changing the .h file to .hpp